# Joda DateTime improper format

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I have a function that returns DateTime

```
public DateTime getCreated() {

  return jodatime;
}
```

It is returning the date in the default ISO8601 format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`. I want to know if I could return DateTime in format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z`.

I am doing:

```
public DateTime getCreated() {

    DateTimeFormatter dtfOut = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    DateTime jodatime = dtfOut.parseDateTime(created.toString(dtfOut));

    return jodatime;
}
```

Each time it returns it is still returning in the default format. This is odd to me because when I output `created.toString(dtfOut)` it outputs the date in the correct format. All suggestions lead to returning a String, but I need to return type DateTime

Comment: A `DateTime` doesn't have a format. It just represents a date and time. The format is added by a `DateTimeFormatter` by converting to a `String` value.

Comment: So this is not possible?

Comment: Just format the `DateTime` when you're about to show it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `DateTime` doesn't *have* a format. Its `toString()` does output a certain, fixed, format, but that is primarily a debugging tool.

If you want your method to return a formatted date string, then it needs to return a `String`, not a `DateTime`:

```
private DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss z");

String getCreatedAsString() {
    return dateTimeFormatter.print(created);
}
```

It's probably cleaner to separate formatting from getting `created`. For example if `getCreated()` is a method in `File`, then `File` shouldn't know anything about how any particular UI happens to display it.

Do any formatting in your presentation layer.

```
System.out.println("Created: " + dateTimeFormatter.print(file.getCreated());
```

Comment: Nice one ... like it. plus one there ;-)

Answer (score 2):

**Formats** only apply when you **convert** your date/time object into a string; or when you create a data/time **from** a string.

In other words: this is "works as designed".

The date/time object knows **nothing** about the format it was created from; or will at some point be formatted to!

Meaning: when the object returned by getCreated() is turned into a string, **then** the format comes into play. And when you **then** provide the format you wish for; *then* you will get what you are asking for - and not the "default" that kicks in if you do not provide a format!